# Is user interaction allowed when running a VBA subroutine via an ActiveX control button?

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I have a subroutine that executes as intended when run from the macro window (ALT+F8).  I can also link a Form button to this sub and it continues to work properly.

Now, when I hook up an ActiveX control button to the sub, click the button, and make sure not to click anything else, the macro executes as intended again.  However, if I click anywhere on the screen while the macro is running, my results come out different than expected.  It seems like user interaction is somehow enabled when running from an ActiveX button.  Even so, why would clicking around the screen alter anything?

Obviously, I could just make sure I don't touch anything while it is executing, or simply use a form button, or just always run the macro from the macro window... but I'd like to understand why it behaves this way.

```
Option Explicit

Sub run_loop()

Const FINALSHEET As String = "Final UV's"
Const VARYYEAR As String = "G6"
Const STARTYEAR As String = "H1"
Const ENDYEAR As String = "H2"
Const OUTPUTVECTOR As String = "G6:G46"
Const DIAGONALVECTOR As String = "H3"

' variable declarations
Dim input_year As Range
Dim vector_out As Range
Dim diagonal_vector As Range

Dim start_year As Integer
Dim end_year As Integer
Dim duration As Integer

' variable initializations
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(FINALSHEET)
    Set input_year = .Range(VARYYEAR)
    Set vector_out = .Range(OUTPUTVECTOR)
    Set diagonal_vector = .Range(DIAGONALVECTOR)

    start_year = .Range(STARTYEAR).Value
    end_year = .Range(ENDYEAR).Value
End With

' clear any prior results
Range(diagonal_vector, Cells(1000, 1000)).Clear

' set initial issue year (loop decrements by 1 immediately so set to 1 higher than initial)
input_year.Value = start_year + 1

' main loop
Do While input_year.Value > end_year   ' ensure that the issue year hasn't gone past the specified end year

    ' decrement the issue year by 1 (sheet auto recalculates at this point)
    input_year.Value = input_year.Value - 1

    ' recalculate duration
    duration = start_year - input_year.Value + 1

    ' copy the resulting vector of UV factors for current issue year to the appropriate column
    vector_out.Offset(0, duration).Value = vector_out.Value

    ' copy diagonal values to a single vector of current year unit values by duration
    diagonal_vector.Offset(0, duration - 1).Value = vector_out(duration + 1, 1)
Loop
End Sub
```

The code for the ActiveX control button lives in the code for the sheet that contains it and simply calls run_loop.

```
Private Sub RunToggle_Click()

run_loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show the code.  You probably have `.select` in your code that needs to be qualified.

Comment: Scott, then it should also fail for the other methods?

Comment: the only i can think of is showing a (non closeable) modal userform which executes the macro (so you cant click anything) and then unload itself after execution ended...

Comment: Don't make us guess - need to see the code in question

Comment: Making you guess was not my intent.  I wasn't intending to make anyone guess.  I thought that perhaps the answer to my question would be obvious to someone.

Comment: Scott's right. `Range(diagonal_vector, Cells(1000, 1000)).Clear` But then why didn't it fail for the other methods?

Comment: Maybe what I should be saying is that the macro ALWAYS works as intended... It copies the results from the 'vector_out' range to an offset column repeatedly.  The issue is that the results in the 'vector_out' range are inconsistent if I happen to click inside the Excel window somewhere while running.

Comment: How do I articulate this better... if the results are inconsistent for activex button, it should be same for form button. Edit: anyways, the only thing unqualified is the `cells` so not sure why.

Comment: The results I'm seeing contradict what you're saying.  The only real difference I see is that for the form button, I can connect it directly to the run_loop sub.  For the ActiveX button, it calls a command contained in the sheet object containing the button, which then calls the run_loop sub.

Comment: ActiveX button has a `TakeFocusOnClick` property whose default value is `True`.  I recall that sometimes being a problem, so you could try setting it to `False`.  Is there any event handler code running for the sheet?

Comment: I added the code for the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but try to replace your line:

```
Range(diagonal_vector, Cells(1000, 1000)).Clear
```

with this line:

```
Range(diagonal_vector, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(FINALSHEET).Cells(1000, 1000)).Clear
```